# bin deploying the odac entity framework dlls with mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle11g, odac

i am getting ready to deploy an mvc 3 application to our servers that uses the oracle entity framework 4.1 beta 
i have used bin deployment in the past for mvc 3 applications for the mvc 3 specific dlls to deploy to a server where mvc 3 was not installed
we currently have oracle instant client for 11g installed on the server and would like to bin deploy the framework components

will this work or do we need to use the xcopy supplement for the odac ef beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODAC EF beta uses a newer version of the instant client, as well as the custom stuff for EF support. You'll have to deploy it along with the application one way or another. I didn't realize there actually was an xcopy version of the beta yet, but that should work.

Comment: ya it looks like ill need to have it installed on the server to the new client